# Is synchronization required when passing a cancel flag with P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am passing a cancel flag by reference (or by pointer) to a C++ DLL by P/Invoke. The flag will be set at some time in C# code, and the C++ code checks for the flag and returns when the flag is set. Is there a need to do synchronization somewhere?

As the C++ code reads the flag while the C# code is writing the flag, a data race is present. "Effective Modern C++" recommends using std::atomic for concurrency to avoid data race problems but it's not available in P/Invoke situation.
I think the flag should be defined as volatile to avoid the C++ compiler to optimize away the read from cancel flag, but I was told that volatile shouldn't be used in concurrency situations.

The C++ function is like this:

```
void doSomething(int &cancelFlag) {
    while (true) {
        ...
        if (cancelFlag != 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: the C# code is like the following. And I found that the "canCancel" is another data race.

```
// token is a CancellationToken
IntPtr cancelFlag = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<int>());
Marshal.WriteInt32(cancelFlag, 0);
bool canCancel = true;
token.Register(() =>
{
    if (canCancel)
    {
        Marshal.WriteInt32(cancelFlag, 1);
    }
});

doSomething(cancelFlag);
canCancel = false;
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cancelFlag);
```

Comment: If you don't use any synchronization, c++ will assume that nothing outside the function can change the cancel flag and it won't even bother to test it more than once - it's either always true or always false within that function.  Depending on the contents of the loop, it may not even test it once since infinite loops with no observable behavior are UB, so it might just assume that cancelflag must be true.

Comment: @xaxxon Is that really true? It would be one thing making that assumption about a local var. But this var is external to this function. Does C++ really assume a single thread of execution, even in modern versions of the standard?

Comment: volatile is to tell a compiler not to be too smart and build a wrong machine code, it's not really for race conditions (plus it doesn't really work for all C compilers). synchronization is a different issue. For a boolean, the race condition risk is to have different copies of the same boolean value (multi core CPU, cache, etc). Since you're already dealing with pointers across worlds, why don't you pass a pointer to a `IsCanceled` C# method that C++ could callback? This way you limit concurrency to one world (C#).

Comment: That C++ code could not work reliably, it does have to use at least std::atomic to access the flag.  Given that it must be another thread inside the C# code that has to change its state.  Requirements for the C# code are also unpleasant, this parameter is an unmanaged pointer and you can't let the pinvoke marshaller create it since another C# thread needs to use it as well.  So the C# code has to use GCHandle.Alloc() to create and pin it, parameter type must be IntPtr.  Fix the C++ code and test it thoroughly before you try to pinvoke it.

Comment: Fwiw, *volatile* can work instead of std::atomic if this code gets compiled to x86 or x64, processors with a strong memory model.  But just get it right off the bat.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the optimizer would be absolutely neutered if it couldn't.   Can you imagine it having to assume that anything can change at any time?   It wouldn't be able to do anything.   Absolutely yes if you don't use synchronization then it can assume nothing else is messing with it.  This is a feature not a bug.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model  Look at the bits about data races.  If you change it outside of synchronization it causes a data race which is UB and the compiler can assume that UB doesn't happen (because if it does then whatever it does is allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using a syncrhonized variable on one side and use a function to access that from the other side.